# Status Bar Color in Android Lollipop with Multiple Theme

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I have one application which I am targeting android 26. Its showing statusbar color fine in above lollipop device. I have managed to show statusbar color in lollipop device with below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            Window window = HomeActivity.this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

**This is working fine but I am using two themes in application and using color as ?attr. I am not able to find use ?attr with java. Let me know if someone have idea to handle this situation. Thanks**